# What is a simple to implement jQuery slider with multiple pictures?

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm searching for a slider that has multiple images. Like 3 images on a row, and when it slides it shows another 3 images.

Anyone know one that is easy to implement and styleable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jCarousel, [as mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322956/what-is-a-simple-to-implement-jquery-slider-with-multiple-pictures/4322999#4322999), is excellent. But if you want a light-weight implementation then I prefer [jCarousel Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) as it is only 2KB and yet is still fully-featured.

Comment: Thanks for the additional advice Dan, i appreciate it! Looks pretty much the same indeed.

Answer (score 4):

one of them is jCarousel: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

this is a demo of your situation: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html

and one with AJAX image fetching: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_ajax_php.html